# Can not run Python on Wine as a root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, wine

I have installed Python 3.10.8 on Wine 7. For downloading modules using pip, I need wine to access the internet. But wine can not access the internet without using sudo. If I run
`wine ping google.com`, the ping test will fail:

```
ali@frozen-flower:~$ wine ping google.com
Pinging google.com [216.239.38.120] with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 216.239.38.120
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

with the help of sudo, everything works:

```
ali@frozen-flower:~$ sudo wine ping google.com
Pinging google.com [216.239.38.120] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.239.38.120: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=102
Reply from 216.239.38.120: bytes=32 time=89ms TTL=102
Reply from 216.239.38.120: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=102
Reply from 216.239.38.120: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=102

Ping statistics for 216.239.38.120
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 70ms, Maximum = 89ms, Average = 76ms
```

The problem is that when I want to run Python on Wine using sudo, I get this error:

```
ali@frozen-flower:~$ sudo wine python
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specifie
d file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.
```

if I don't use sudo, Python will run:

```
ali@frozen-flower:~$ wine python
Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (
AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

My ubuntu version is 22.10

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe this question about an older version helps: https://askubuntu.com/q/732436/1186757 Did you install wine from an official Ubuntu 22.10 package? Please [edit] your question to add information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem after some investigations. When you install Wine, you need to configure it using the `winecfg` command. If you run this command without `sudo`, Wine will create its folder (i.e. `.wine`) inside `/home/$user` but If you run `sudo winecfg`, the `.wine` folder will be created under the `/root` folder. It means that you will have two instances of Wine in your machine. I read on some websites that running Wine with `sudo` will cause some apps to be able to connect to the internet (although some other apps can access the internet without using `sudo` which means connecting to the internet in some apps requires creating specific types of socket that can not be created unless you are root). So you have to install Python in the Wine instance that uses `/root/.wine` (i.e. running the Python installer with `sudo wine`).